# "Node JS installation receive error "The repository does not have a Release file"

Tags: node.js

I am very new Node.JS, and I am trying to run the following installation script in ubuntu and receive a few errors:

- Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu
  xenial/main amd64 Packages
       404  Not Found
- W: The repository
  'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xe
  nial Release' does not have a Release file.

Sorry for the bad format in stackoverflow

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -

### Installing the NodeSource Node.js 8.x LTS Carbon repo...

### Populating apt-get cache...

- apt-get update

  Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable InRelease
  Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]
  Hit:3 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
  Hit:4 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Hit:5 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb preview InRelease
  Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Get:7 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
  Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable Release
  Hit:10 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
  Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Get:13 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
  Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial Release
  Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
  Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
  Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_AU
  Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
  Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
  Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
  Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_AU
  Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
  Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
  Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
  Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_AU
  Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
  Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
  Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
  Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_AU
  Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
  Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
  Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
  Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_AU
  Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
  Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
    404  Not Found
  Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
  Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
  Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_AU
  Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
  Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  Fetched 323 kB in 52s (6,179 B/s)
  Reading package lists... Done
  W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
  N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
  N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
  E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
  E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
  Error executing command, exiting

Comment: If you want to install Node.js on ubuntu I reccomend  you to do it through  NVM. NVM (Node Version Manager) will save you from headaches in the future. Here is a tutorial you can follow https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18-04.

Comment: I will give try, thanks